# Django 1.6+ test not Discovering unit tests located in a tests sub-directory

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

So I have looked at no less than 10 different Stack Overflow questions related to Django not finding unit tests, and everyone one of them still doesn't fix my issue.

I am running Django 1.65 and am trying to get Django to discover my tests.

Here is my directory structure

```
project
  __init__.py
  my_app
    __init__.py
    tests
      __init__.py
      test_template_tags.py
  my_app2
    __init__.py
    tests
      __init__.py
      test_something_else.py
```

The command I am trying at the command line inside the project directory is:
`python manage.py test my_app`

The code inside test_template_tags.py is:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestClass(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
      pass

  def tearDown(self):
      pass

  def test_something(self):
      self.assertTrue(True)
```

From a tip in another SO this command `find my_app -name 'test*.py'` was executed and shows all test files as one would expect.

When I open up the django shell inside of the project directory and attempt to import the test class, everything works as expected.

`from my_app.tests.test_template_tags import MyTestClass`

Lastly I copied and pasted the testing code into a tests.py file inside the app directory, and of course, it worked, but its not the solution I am looking for.

Is there some other obvious small thing that I'm missing here? I have all my `__init__.py` files in order, all test files have `test_` in the front, and my_app is included in the `INSTALLED_APPLICATIONS` in settings.

Answer (score 3):

Before trying any of the answers here, make sure your test files are, by convention, labelled `test*.py`.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! No need to modify __init__.py

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__.py` you need to `import` the other test modules in that directory in order for the test runner to discover them.  If your structure looks like this:

```
project
  __init__.py
  my_app
    __init__.py
    tests
      __init__.py
      test_template_tags.py
  my_app2
    __init__.py
    tests
      __init__.py
      test_something_else.py
```

Then `my_app.tests.__init__.py` would contain:

```
from test_template_tags import *
```

And `my_app2.tests.__init__.py` would contain:

```
from test_something_else import *
```

Then your tests will run using `python manage.py test`

Comment: So this definitely works, I'm not 100% crazy about it, but if that's how its supposed to be done, that's what I'll do. Is this how Django was intending it when they changed test runners? (Obviously there was more to the decision than just this).

Comment: This is how all of python works actually.  You have to import all `.py` files in a directory into the `__init__.py` file in order for python to be able to find those modules.

Comment: I'm not following what you're saying. There's no reason they couldn't just have a recursive Discovery process that looked for test* files. If I wanted to have multiple test directories, and or nested directories, do I then have to import them all in that single `__init__.py` file?

To me the simple fact of importing it into the `__init__.py` is kind of in a way redundant, and in violation of DIY because the file system has that info. Typically I've seen `__init__.py` used to be the location of where you wanted certain parts of the package to be loaded/executed.

Comment: Another thought I had regarding this technique. The requirement for doing a `from module import *` seems like a code smell / red flag to me. This is one of those situations labeled a bad practice. http://bit.ly/1qhJxaq the writer of this blog labels it a "worst practice".

Comment: I was going to add that to my comment.  Actually, this is one of the only times that you want to use `from module import *`. That is a design decision of coarse.  You can import your `test classes` individually if you want.

Comment: I was going to provide an answer, but realized, my configuration was wrong, and it still stands.

When you examine the default way that the unittest python Discovery works, you point it at a directory and it recurses through it looking for `test*.py` files. It works exactly how I want it to. The Django one doesn't work like that. I opened up the shell and loaded their Discovery class in and use it to "discover", and low and behold it found my test classes. No configuration, no changes whatsoever.
But for some reason from the command line it doesn't. I hadn't walked the source yet to find why.

Comment: I'm using django 4.2, and the discovery process works without importing in `__init__.py`